# Ansible group module

Tags: ansible

In the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_module.html) there is an option for a system group. What exactly is a system group? I couldn't find this detail anywhere.

```
If yes, indicates that the group created is a system group.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“System groups” are usually lower numbered than non-system, commonly 0-99. There’s a little relevant info in the `groupadd(8)` man page:

> -r, --system
>         Create a system group.
>
> ```
>   The numeric identifiers of new system groups are chosen in the
>   SYS_GID_MIN-SYS_GID_MAX range, defined in login.defs, instead of
>   GID_MIN-GID_MAX.
> ```

Example groups are http, dbus, wheel, mail.

More details in [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80277/whats-the-difference-between-a-normal-user-and-a-system-user).